# Is this move legal in predicate logic ( quantifying universally over a variable about which one has no information)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Context : find a counter example to the statement $$∀x∈C(∃y∈C(y∈A)⇒¬(x∈B))$$

---

Suppose I know that there is some x such that : x belongs to set C but NOT to set B.

Am I allowed to derive from this that :

for all ***y*** (y does not belong to C OR y does not belong to A OR x does not belong to B)

It seems to me that " x does not belong to B" being true, that makes the whole disjunction true for any variable ( even if I have no information on this variable coming from elsewhere).

Is there an official rule that makes this derivation legal in predicate logic natural deduction?

Comment: If $x$ is "whatever" (i.e. nothing has been assumed about it, yes the move is legal; it is called [Universal Generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

Comment: But to assume that "there is some x such that : x belongs to set C but NOT to set B" dose not implies that this will be true for every $x$ whatever. The UG rule is correctly applied if we have proved, for an $x$ whatever, that "x belongs to set C but NOT to set B".

Comment: Write it in formulas: it is simpler. You want to derive $\forall y [\lnot C(y) \lor \lnot A(y) \lor \lnot B(x)]$. Your assumption is $(C(x) \land \lnot B(x))$, for some $x$. The trick is "for some"; if you mean $\exists x$, the derivation is not correct.

Comment: @Mauro Allegranza. In the sentence I want to derive, the universal quantification bares on a new variable y . Does this make a difference?

Comment: If instead you have proved $C(x) \land \lnot B(x)$, for $x$ whatever, this means $\forall x (C(x) \land \lnot B(x))$, form which $\forall x \lnot B(x)$. Now, from $B(x)$ we have $B(x) \lor \varphi (y)$ for $\varphi$ whatever, and then we can generalize on $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Context : find a counter example to the statement $$∀x∈C(∃y∈C(y∈A)⇒¬(x∈B))$$
>
> It seems to me that " x does not belong to B" being true, that makes the whole disjunction true for any variable ( even if I have no information on this variable coming from elsewhere).

Indeed, when $C$ and $B$ are disjoint sets, then the statement would be *true*.   So that can *not* serve as a **counter**example.

Your approach is no good.   You should seek an interpretation of the sets which makes the statement *false*.

Now, recall that an implication is false *only when* the antecedent is *true* but the consequent is *false*.

So you want $A,B,C$ to be such that the *negation* of the statement, ie $\exists x\in C~((\exists y\in C~(y\in A))\wedge(x\in B))$, is true.